# My phone displays: "Notification has been set" at each boot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications, popup

I am in doubt. My Galaxy SII phone began recently to display a standard pop-up notification box with the text "Notification has been set" at each boot. I uninstalled the software that I suspected was displaying this popup, there were no notifications in notification area left, but this popup has kept appearing on the screen.

How to track which software is displaying this popup?

Android 4.0.4

Comment: What kind of "standard pop-up notification box" is it? Is it a *dialog* that appears in the middle of the screen (and you have to press a button to get rid of it), or a *toast* that appears near the bottom of the screen for a few seconds, or a *notification* that shows an icon in the notification bar?

Comment: Also, my first look would be the logs (`logcat`). When in doubt how to look at them, search for "logcat" on Google play -- lots of apps to help you there. With some look, filtering the system logs for "notification" will bring up the culprit.

Comment: @Dan Hulme: it is a "toast". Thank you for the terminology.

Comment: @Izzy: I studied the logcat through, but haven't found any decent culprit. May be I have overlooked it. I'll look more attentive in a couple of days.

Comment: --From another user-- "I also just got this on my LG Optimus G running 4.1.2 My phone also vibrated a few times for nothing without anything in the notification bar... I've looked through the logcat without much success. The only recent thing I've changed is I've updated from Swype Beta to the paid one from Google Play"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. I messed around with `adb logcat`, `adb shell dumpsys` and Titanium Backup's Freeze feature. I have succesfully narrowed it down (on my device) to an App called "Pullups 2.04" by "NorthPark" from the Play Store.

Comment: I'm not sure new users can reply as a comment, I'll add this for you to the question but I've flagged this answer for deletion.

Comment: Yea I just read on that, seems I need rep before replying as a comment on a post other than mine. Anyway, I think I just found the answer, at least for the exact same toast notificaiton on my phone..

Comment: Well since you seem to have found a possible answer there's a +1 so you can comment, and I'm not sure how to remove a flag but sure the mods will see this.

Comment: Thank you for the exact information! Unlike you I had multiple applications from NorthPark: Pull ups, Push ups, Sit ups, Squats. To make this toast disappear I had to remove all of them. These applications make this toast appear although they have notifications turned off in their settings.